# jQuery DataTables Plugin Callback

Tags: jquery, datatable

I need to cache the html of the table before applying [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net) plugin.
I used to do it by caching the html and after it applying the plgin:

```
var originalTableHtml = escape($('#DataTable').parent().html());
$('#DataTable').dataTable(DataTableOpts);
```

However, now I need to do it somehow in another to do it. Is there any way to apply a callback "on DataTable Init"..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by editing the plugin and creating a "before init" callback.